# Convert a PHP website to an Android App

Tags: php, android, html

This question may seem off-leading but I want to convert my website in to an actual android app. There were suggestions that I should just create a custom-web browser and that the address will then lead to my website which of course looks like the app is the website itself, but what if I'd like to "convert" like code-for-code in to android's IDE? Is this possible?

Because when I stick to the "browser" method, sometimes, since it has to load the HTML, CSS, JS and etc. I'd like to make it "rooted" to the Android app like it's already there so that when it connects to the internet, it will only get my MSQL data and skip the whole HTML, CSS, ... loading stuffs everytime they visit my page.

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try at `webview`. It is a View that displays web pages. This class is the basis upon which you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online content within your Activity. It uses the WebKit rendering engine to display web pages and includes methods to navigate forward and backward through a history, zoom in and out, perform text searches and more.

You can explore from the following link: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use ionic/cordova to create a webview that will browse the live website on the app load. Alternatively you can use online service such as [applika.me](https://www.applika.me/create) that does more of the same.